# How to set and return session id in headers in web api2

Tags: c#, session, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

After successful login I want to return `session_id` in response headers and along with that some object I want to return.

My typical response header is as follows.

```
Response
Header: Set-cookie: session_id=121212-343dsfsd-4323132, path=/, expires: 1212
Body: {
    “status”: 0,
    “data”: {
        “userRole”: “SUPER_ADMIN”
    }
}
```

I am trying as below to achieve above.

```
bool result = //...validate username and password with database

if(result == true)
{
    SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
    string newSessionId= manager.CreateSessionID(HttpContext.Current);
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id",newSessionId);
    cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
    cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
    cookie.Path = "/";
    resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
    //return resp;
    obj.UserRole = (from c in entityObject.NCT_UserRegistration where obj.User_Name == c.User_Name && obj.User_Password == c.User_Password select c.User_Role).FirstOrDefault();
    obj.Success = 0;
    obj.User_Password="";
    return Ok(obj);
}
```

I am not sure the way I followed correct or not. How can I return `sessionid` as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor the above code as follows

```
if(result == true) {

    obj.UserRole = (from c in entityObject.NCT_UserRegistration where obj.User_Name == c.User_Name && obj.User_Password == c.User_Password select c.User_Role).FirstOrDefault();
    obj.Success = 0;
    obj.User_Password = "";

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);

    var newSessionId = new SessionIDManager().CreateSessionID(HttpContext.Current);
    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", newSessionId);
    cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
    cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
    cookie.Path = "/";

    response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });

    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

Main difference is how the response is created and returned. The original code was creating a new response manually, populating it with cookie and then returning another completely different response that had the body minus cookie. ie: `Ok(obj)`.

The above code creates a response that includes the object value to be returned and then the cookie header information is added to the response.

If the original intention of the OP was to return `IHttpActionResult`, then `ResponseMessage(response)` will wrap the `HttpResponseMessage` in a `IHttpActionResult` derived implementation.